Karate Framework: Fonts comparison (Image comparison) between 2 applications
We are trying to identify the difference between 2 applications using the same font type.
Application A i am using Font Family "Bodoni MT Black" and in Application B i am selecting the same font family and comparing the Font style's are same and it is exactly similar.
Negative scenario is
Application A i am selecting a Font Family "Bodoni MT Black" and removing this font from OS so that it will select some default Font type and verifying these 2 fonts are different.

I tried with Karate Image comparison feature using ignore Box option and selected only the specific porting from second application
Please help me to do this font comparison using the Karate Image comparison feature


image comparison was contributed by the community, my suggestion is try to contribute code or join the discussion, here is the link to original issue: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/2141
